# How to run multiple feature files in selenium+nodejs?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, cucumberjs

How to run multiple feature files in selenium+nodejs + cucumberjs ?

Answer (score 1):

As per your query it looks like you want to know something about the parallel execution of your code
It majorly depends on your framework and also build tool you use in your project, which will help you to manage the threads running in your project and tests.
Jasmine is one of the modules in node which can be used in cucumber and selenium to achieve parallel execution.

Answer (score 1):

To run multiple features at the same time you must have proper entry in your protractor config file:

```
capabilities: {
        maxInstances: 3
    },
```

This will run 3 features at the same time in a separate browser instances.